# Counting number of times a value occurs and sending count to another column?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table that I have fed data into through a PHP script, and am managing it using phpMyAdmin. My table has 4 columns. The first is an auto increment, second and third are values being fed in, and the final is meant to keep track of how many times the value from column 3 has appeared.

This is how my table currently appears

```
RowNumber   UserID  SongID  Plays
1             540   2191    0
2             540   2671    0
3             550   3891    0
4             550   2191    0
5             550   2671    0
6             560   9391    0
7             560   2191    0
```

I want to search through the whole table and change the value in the Plays column to show how many times the value appears in the table.

Ideally, this is how I want my table to output:

```
RowNumber   UserID  SongID  Plays
1             540   2191    3
2             540   2671    2
3             550   3891    1
4             550   2191    3
5             550   2671    2
6             560   9391    1
7             560   2191    3
```

Is there a way to search through the table and update these values?
The amount of data being inputted into the table is quite large, so an efficient solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a view instead of a table, unless you need the value cached for performance reasons.  You can compute the count of each value in a subquery and join the results back to the table like so:

```
SELECT Table.RowNumber, Table.UserID, Table.SongID, x.Plays
FROM Table
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SongID, COUNT(*) AS Plays
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY SongID
) x
ON Table.SongID = x.SongID;
```

And create a view from it using `CREATE VIEW TableWithPlays AS SELECT ...`.  Having an index on `SongID` will allow the subquery to complete rather quickly, and you will never have to worry about the `Plays` column being up to date.

If you do in fact want to cache the values, use an `UPDATE` query based on the above query:

```
UPDATE Table a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SongID, COUNT(*) AS Plays
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY SongID
) b
ON a.SongID = b.SongID
SET Plays = b.Plays;
```

As with the view solution, don't forget the index on `SongID`.

Comment: Mmmm there must be an `INSERT` somewhere

Comment: Ah, I missed that the table needs to be updated.  (And I think you mean `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Could you expand a bit on what a and b are in your second example?

Comment: @Ndrd They are table/query aliases, and make it easier to refer to which table a particular column is on.  In the case of the subquery, it is *required* to be able to refer to one of its columns, since it has no name otherwise.  (Aliases are particularly useful when joining a table to itself, since you would not otherwise be able to indicate a column on one of the two incarnations of the table.)

Comment: So when you're checking a.SongID against b.SongID they're columns from different tables? Why are 'a' and 'b' used where they are in your example? Sorry for the questions, but I'm quite new to MySQL and am a little confused how to implement this.

Comment: @Ndrd Table aliases are established when the table is introduced: `UPDATE Table a` <-- the `a` here declares the alias, and the same for the `b` following the subquery.  `b` becomes the name of the subquery's projection.  So columns on `a` refer to columns of the `Table` table, and colunms on `b` refer to the projected columns of the subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it all makes sense now. It might be worth mentioning that I had to change the Plays after the count in order for it not to conflict with the  existing plays column.

Comment: @Ndrd It should not conflict... if it does can you paste the error?

Comment: It was not returning an error, but it was not updating the values in the Plays column. The query I used in the end was: `mysql_query("UPDATE usersong a
       INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SongID, COUNT(*) AS Play
        FROM usersong
        GROUP BY SongID
        ) b
        ON a.SongID = b.SongID
        SET Plays = b.Play");`

Comment: Odd, it should have either given an error or update the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use simple PHP query that is run periodically (**Note: not an actual code**):

```
$sql = "SELECT UserID, SongID, COUNT(RowNumber) AS CNT FROM SomeTable GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 3 ASC";

foreach($result as $row){
   $sql = "UPDATE SomeTable SET Plays = ".$row['CNT']." WHERE UserID = '" . $row['UserID'] . "' AND SongID = '" . $row['SongID'] . "'";
}
```